# Fall back for Base64 Encode in http transfer of OpenSSL encrypted messages?

Tags: php, openssl, base64, message-passing

Here's the scenario:

I have 2 sites, example1.com and example2.com. I'm passing messages between them, using WP's wp_remote_post method and OpenSSL for encryption. On site example1.com, which initiates the communication, I use the private key for encryption and on example2.com, a public key corresponding to the private key is used for decryption. For transferring it over the web, I use Base64 Encode on example1.com for encoding the data to be sent. Now the problem is, example2.com's server has Base64 disabled (or atleast what I understand from the warning<sup>#</sup> I get!) so I can't use it for decoding.

> Warning: base64_decode() has been disabled for
>   security reasons...

Hence is there another way, a fall back for Base64 that can be used for encoding the private key encrypted message, and one which is supported by default?

Note: Both the sites are WordPress sites, and obviously, the language is PHP.

Comment: base64 is in PHP by default .... what do you mean disabled ???

Comment: Do you want me to help you resolve the error or give you another encoding you can work with ??? like Hex

Comment: Resolving the error would be nice!

Comment: Do you have access to php.ini ??

Comment: wow ... ok i'll update my answer to give you other options

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/9072/discussion-between-baba-and-rutwick-gangurde)